# Unable to do raster operations in R

Tags: r, raster, qgis

Hi my raster values for a Raster Layer are the following:

```
dimensions : 2225, 2286, 5086350  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.03333146, 0.03333146  (x, y)
extent     : -20.86612, 55.32961, -35.40306, 38.75945  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : solar.tif 
names      : solar 
values     : 0, 2855  (min, max)
```

However whenever I try to do simple raster operations such as:

```
plot(solar)
```

It returns this error:

```
Error in setValues(outras, m) : 
  could not find symbol "values" in environment of the generic function
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: try `str(solar)` - maybe this will give you some insight into the problem

Comment: this may go away after you run `update.packages(ask=FALSE)`